# Lmer() - show the whole output of summary()

Tags: r

I have the following model:

```
lmer(Score~Closure*ExpertiseType+Expertise*LastPosition+Closure*LastPosition+(1|Participant)+(1|Item), data = datasheet.complete, REML = TRUE)
```

When I summary (model), I get 32 results. However the results should be more, as the function give me information about two out of three interactions (only Closure*ExpertiseType and ExpertiseType*LastPosition, while Closure*LastPosition is cut out).

Is there a way to view all the results of the lmer()?

---

I have chosen the model through comparison. Here the model comparison and the results:

```
modela = lmer(Score~1+(1|Participant)+(1|Item), data = datasheet.complete, REML = TRUE)
modelb = update(modela,.~.+ExpertiseType)
modelc = update(modelb,.~.+Closure)
modeld = update(modelc,.~.+LastPosition)
modele = update(modeld,.~.+ExpertiseType*Closure)
modelf = update(modele,.~.+ExpertiseType*LastPosition)
modelg = update(modelf,~.+Closure*LastPosition)
anova(modela,modelb,modelc,modeld,modele,modelf,modelg)

       Df   AIC   BIC logLik deviance   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
modela  4 24694 24722 -12343    24686                              
modelb  6 24697 24739 -12343    24685  1.2965      2   0.522967    
modelc  9 24696 24759 -12339    24678  6.9578      3   0.073255 .  
modeld 16 24662 24774 -12315    24630 47.9619      7  3.622e-08 ***
modele 22 24636 24790 -12296    24592 38.7574      6  7.985e-07 ***
modelf 36 24601 24853 -12264    24529 62.5349     14  4.195e-08 ***
modelg 57 24600 25000 -12243    24486 43.1038     21   0.003049 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Does this mean that I have enough data for modelg? I have in total 8200 data. Here instead the output (t value and Pr only for brevity)

```
model = lmer(Score~Closure*ExpertiseType+ExpertiseType*LastPosition+Closure*LastPosition+(1|Participant)+(1|Item), data = datasheet.complete, REML = TRUE)
summary(model)

                                        t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              43.673  < 2e-16 ***
Closurecl_c1                             -0.005  0.99616    
Closurecl_c2                             -0.905  0.36547    
Closurecl_c3                              1.752  0.07979 .  
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1                      -0.213  0.83270    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2                       1.197  0.23853    
LastPosition.pos_c1                       2.306  0.02114 *  
LastPositionpos2                          4.379 1.20e-05 ***
LastPositionpos3                          2.680  0.00738 ** 
LastPositionpos4                          0.850  0.39550    
LastPositionpos5                         -2.353  0.01865 *  
LastPositionpos6                         -0.295  0.76787    
LastPositionpos7                          2.720  0.00655 ** 
Closurecl_c1:ExpertiseTypeexp_c1         -0.663  0.50738    
Closurecl_c2:ExpertiseTypeexp_c1          2.556  0.01059 *  
Closurecl_c3:ExpertiseTypeexp_c1          5.494 4.05e-08 ***
Closurecl_c1:ExpertiseTypeexp_c2         -1.390  0.16460    
Closurecl_c2:ExpertiseTypeexp_c2         -0.347  0.72870    
Closurecl_c3:ExpertiseTypeexp_c2         -1.270  0.20394    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPosition.pos_c1   4.069 4.77e-05 ***
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPosition.pos_c1   0.424  0.67125    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos2      2.733  0.00630 ** 
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos2      0.147  0.88285    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos3     -0.481  0.63030    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos3     -0.865  0.38688    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos4     -3.134  0.00173 ** 
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos4      1.574  0.11564    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos5     -0.205  0.83736    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos5     -1.352  0.17644    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos6     -1.582  0.11374    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos6      1.194  0.23248    
ExpertiseTypeexp_c1:LastPositionpos7      4.333 1.49e-05 ***
ExpertiseTypeexp_c2:LastPositionpos7      1.063  0.28801    
Closurecl_c1:LastPosition.pos_c1         -2.309  0.02095 *  
Closurecl_c2:LastPosition.pos_c1         -3.241  0.00119 ** 
Closurecl_c3:LastPosition.pos_c1         -2.222  0.02628 *  
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos2            -0.706  0.48044    
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos2            -1.540  0.12367    
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos2            -0.304  0.76125    
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos3             1.572  0.11604    
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos3            -1.057  0.29054    
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos3            -0.271  0.78661    
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos4             1.871  0.06142 .  
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos4             0.229  0.81925    
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos4            -0.229  0.81875    
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos5             1.036  0.30022    
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos5            -1.314  0.18876    
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos5             0.315  0.75256    
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos6             0.681  0.49584    
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos6             1.398  0.16216    
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos6             0.248  0.80452    
Closurecl_c1:LastPositionpos7             0.105  0.91666    
Closurecl_c2:LastPositionpos7             1.880  0.06017 .  
Closurecl_c3:LastPositionpos7            -1.936  0.05287 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 54 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
     vcov(x)     if you need it
```

As I have created a rectangular contrast matrix, LastPosition.pos_c1 is the actual contrast hypothesis. LastPositionpos1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7 mean nothing instead, as it is a product of the rectangular->square transformation. As you can see, in the output there are only 2 two-way interactions out of 3. I don't understand where the last has ended.

Comment: Do you have enough data to estimate all the coefficients, or is it just missing out the reference category? Can you add the `str` of your data, and the results of `summary` (including any warnings) please

Comment: @user20650, I don't know what a str is, so I tried to update the post in the most useful way possible.

Comment: Thanks for the update Luca. Your question states _"Closure*LastPosition is cut out"_ but from your summary the coefficients are shown? Also, by _"there are only 2 two-way interactions out of 3"_ do you mean that you expect 3-way interactions between Closure, LastPosition, and ExpertiseType; if so , you have not added 3-way interactions to your model. (ps if you look at `str(datasheet.complete)` it lets you see the class of the variables, data size, levels of factors etc - so it can be useful to add to questions to quickly provide details)

Comment: @user20650 that is true.. and to be honest it's quite embarrassing.. Don't know what's happened in my mind. Everything is already there. Sorry for the trouble for nothing

Comment: ha, no problem, we all get brain melt. Probably worth deleting this

Comment: @user20650 Ah no, indeed!! Before I wrote that I was seeing 32 outputs, but now they are more!! Probably doing a fresh analysis has cleared out things

Comment: @user20650, yep.. I will delete this now. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R studio, store the summary in a new variable or name, and then when this new variable shows up in the workspace in R studio, click it to open it in a new tab. This way you can see all the elements stored in the summary object.